# Trying to upload a file from controller using HttpWebRequest method to API Action that has an argument of [FromForm] IFormFile file receives null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload a file from Controller to API in asp.net core mvc. The method of the API which should recive the file is given below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ReservationController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadFile ([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Now on my other project there is a View that contains file upload control:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <div class="text-center panel-body">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now on the submit button the controller action that gets called is :

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddFile(IFormFile file)
{
    HttpWebRequest apiRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation") as HttpWebRequest;
    apiRequest.Method = "Post";
    apiRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    string apiResponse = "";
    using (HttpWebResponse response = apiRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            apiResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
  }
```

The IFormFile file gets the file. Upto that point it is working fine.

**Problem**

Now I am creating object of HttpWebRequest to upload my file using API method.

The API method gets called but i **revived null value** i.e. on the below method the 'file' parameter gets null?

```
[HttpPost]
public void UploadFile ([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
}
```

**Why it is so? please help?**

**NOTE**

If i just change the view to include action attribute on the form to the URL of my API then it works:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation/UploadFile">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <div class="text-center panel-body">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Since i want to do it from controller and get back the response therefore I want to make API call from Controller.

Comment: Have you tried removing `[FromForm]`?

Comment: @AntonToshik I want the [FromForm]. If i just change the form action on the view to http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation then it works. But I want to do from controller so that I can get back the response too.

Comment: You don't attach the file anywhere in your request to the api.

Comment: @AntonToshik will it not be automatically send. If not how to attach the file in the controller code? Can you give me the code in the answer for this. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFormFile` specifically only works with `multipart/form-data` encoding, which is why it arrives fine in your first action. However, in the request you're making there, the biggest issue is that you aren't actually even sending the file in the request in the first place. Then, you would also need to use `multipart/form-data` rather than `application/octet-stream`.

Handling this via `WebRequest` is actually fairly complex, and `HttpClient` is the preferred way to make requests anyways. With `HttpClient`:

```
string apiResponse;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        form.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), "file", file.Filename);
        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, form))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
     }
 }
```

I wanted to make the example intentionally simple, but you actually should not use `HttpClient` like this. It should be treated as a singleton, for the most part, which is thankfully fairly easy via `IHttpClientFactory`. First, you're going to need some sort of wrapper class, which is a good idea anyways when you're working with an API:

```
public class ReservationService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ReservationService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    }

    public async Task<string> AddFileAsync(IFormFile file)
    {
        var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            form.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), "file", file.Filename);
            using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("", form))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<ReservationService>();

services.AddHttpClient<ReservationService>(c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/api/Reservation");
});
```

Finally, in your controller:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly ReservationService _service;

    public FooController(ReservationService service)
    {
        _service = service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
    }

    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        var apiResponse = await _service.AddFileAsync(file);
        // whatever else you want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Finest answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle file uploads in .net core using HttpClient

```
public async Task<string> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    Client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/api/") };

    HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
    var multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        { fileStreamContent, "file", "file.FileName" }
    };

    var response = await Client.PostAsync("Reservation", multiContent);
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();;
    return data;
}
```